# How to get instance of ViewModel inside Service?

Tags: android, mvvm

I'm trying to get instance from my ViewModel inside the service onStartCommand method.

```
LogRecordsViewModel logRecordsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(?????).get(LogRecordsViewModel.class);
```

> So, what should be placed as argument inside .of()?

Appreciate help

Comment: Why would you use `ViewModel` inside your `Service` at all? `ViewModel` already suggests that it's a model for a `View`, not for a `Service`, for instance.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I think I was misunderstanding it.